# How to check property value of object

Tags: c#, properties

i want do some action if value of property in object is equal something.

My object:

```
//abstract class Tile.cs
namespace DungeonGame.Tiles
{
    public abstract class Tile
    {
        public abstract string Type { get; set; }
    }
}
//Item.cs that iherits from Tile.cs
namespace DungeonGame
{
    public class Item : Tile
    {
        public override string Type { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }


        public Item(string name)
        {
            this.Type = "item";
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

And i have several objects in `public Object[,] BoardTiles { get; private set; }`, I had to store different types of tiles in same place so i had to use Object type array.
What i'm trying to do is replace array index with different type of object, depending of the value of property **(In this case I set value depending of object type not his value of property)**:

```
public void movefillRight(int playerPositionRowIndex, int playerPositionColumnIndex)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < Rows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < Cols; c++)

                {
                    if (BoardTiles[playerPositionRowIndex, playerPositionColumnIndex ].GetType().ToString() == ("DungeonGame.Item"))
                    {
/*                        placePlayerOnTheBoard(playerPositionRowIndex, playerPositionColumnIndex, PlayerTile);
*/                        BoardTiles[playerPositionRowIndex, playerPositionColumnIndex] = Item1;
                        BoardTiles[playerPositionRowIndex, playerPositionColumnIndex - 1] = Floor;
                    }
                    else if (BoardTiles[playerPositionRowIndex, playerPositionColumnIndex-1].GetType().ToString() == ("DungeonGame.Item"))
                    {
                        BoardTiles[playerPositionRowIndex, playerPositionColumnIndex-1] = Item1;
                        placePlayerOnTheBoard(playerPositionRowIndex, playerPositionColumnIndex, PlayerTile);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        placePlayerOnTheBoard(playerPositionRowIndex, playerPositionColumnIndex, PlayerTile);
                        BoardTiles[playerPositionRowIndex, playerPositionColumnIndex - 1] = Floor;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(BoardTiles[playerPositionRowIndex, playerPositionColumnIndex].GetType().ToString());//log
        }
```

The functionality of the function is to leave the same object on the same index when the player walks over it, so the problem is that code is ok when I  have one Item, for example only sword, but when there are more items i can replace index always with same object but not with object witch different properties, when the player walks over a good sword and bad sword (same object, but another properties) he leave behind just sword...  I have idea how to solve this problem but i need to refer to property value which is at specific index of my object array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you check that the item in the array is of a specific type you can then [cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#cast-expression) it.

```
if (BoardTiles[playerPositionRowIndex, playerPositionColumnIndex ].GetType().ToString() == ("DungeonGame.Item"))
{
    var item = (DungeonGame.Item)BoardTiles[playerPositionRowIndex, playerPositionColumnIndex];
    Console.Writeline(item.Name);
}
```

Comment: Than you for answer, I think this is what I was looking for :)